# Prevent class's users to use setters

Tags: c#, oop, frameworks

I'm trying to implement a simple sprite animating framework with C#. I have classes that have getters and setters. It's OK for me that using this getters and setters but the user of this framework should not see and use this setters. How can I achieve that?

Comment: make the setter private

Comment: @ratchetfreak But I'm using this setter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check out the [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) accessibility modifier, similar to `public` or `private`, but allowing access to the modified properties only to code compiled as part of the same assembly. You can specify it on the setter only, just like using `private`.

```
public string MyProperty {get; internal set;}
```

Of course, this isn't perfect. If your own framework is comprised of several assemblies, they would run into accessibility problems too. One option is to structure your solution accordingly. Another is to use the [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute, which lets an assembly explicitly name an external assembly as a "friend", allowing it access to its `internal` members.

Comment: Assuming that I won't use this setter in another project, internal will solve my problem. Did I understand that correctly?

Comment: Yes. The (updated) code snippet I posted will allow the getter to be accessible by anyone, and the setter only by code compiled in the same DLL/EXE.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of using explicit interfaces for this sort of situation... but "internal" will obviously do the job if the framework is contained within a single assembly.